# How to debug CustomServiceHostFactory in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I've recently implemented a CustomServiceHostFactory and am wondering how to debug it by hitting breakpoints in code. Here is the factory:

```
public class CustomHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

        //configure WsHttpBinding
        ConfigureServiceThrottling(host);

        return host;
    }

    private void ConfigureWshttpBinding(ServiceHost host)
    {
        //Do something here....
    }
    private void ConfigureServiceThrottling(ServiceHost host)
    {
        ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttle = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceThrottlingBehavior>();

        if (throttle == null)
        {
            throttle = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 100,
                MaxConcurrentSessions = 100,
                MaxConcurrentInstances = 100
            };

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttle);
        }
    }
}
```

I create this in an empty web project and here are the pertinent Web.config contents.

```
  <service name="Company.Project.Business.Services.AccountService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="Company.Project.Business.Contracts.Service.IAccountService"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>

  <service name="Company.Project.Business.Services.AccountClassService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="Company.Project.Business.Contracts.Service.IAccountClassService"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />

  </service>               
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <!-- where virtual .svc files are defined -->
  <serviceActivations>        
    <add service="Company.Project.Business.Services.AccountService" 
         relativeAddress="AccountService.svc" 
         factory="Company.Project.WebHost.CustomHostFactory"/>

    <add service="Company.Project.Business.Services.AccountClassService" 
         relativeAddress="AccountClassService.svc" 
         factory="Company.Project.WebHost.CustomHostFactory"/>

  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

I publish this to IIS and can successfully browse to and consume the services. Here is a path to one for example.

http://company.server.local/Project/Account/AccountService.svc

I am now trying to programmatically apply WsHttpBinding with open/close/send timeouts, readerQuotas, etc. I am trying to do this all in code and it would be helpful if I could step into the CustomeHostFactory to debug but have no idea how to do that. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are your breakpoints not working or did you not press F9?

Comment: The CustomHostFactory web project is not the start up project. In the WPF consumer, I manually created a proxy and the .config points to where the web project is published in IIS. Thus, when debugging with the WPF client as start project, you never get into the CustomHostFactory.

Comment: You can set multiple startup projects. If you set the web project as well, your breakpoints there should be hit.

Comment: I set both as startup and still don't get in. Do I have to change endpoints to localhost or something? I don't even have IIS installed locally.

Comment: If it's hosted in IIS then it will be run in the w3wp.exe process.  In VS when the WPF app is running click on Debug > Attach to process, then select w3wp.exe.  It should attach and let you debug ok.

Comment: I don't see w3wp.exe in the list. FYI I manually create the proxy on the client side if that makes a difference, not sure.

Comment: Make sure you select "Show processes from all users".  Failing that, open IIS Manager and try browsing the service manually, that should make sure the w3wp process is started.

Comment: I've done that and still nothing. Again I'm using a CustomHostFactory so with relative addressing so there is no .svc file published, but I can browse to the AccountService.svc and I do see the service is created as well as the wsdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was totally confused here. Instead of trying to attach to the w3wp process, I just set the project with the CustomHostFactory as the startup project in Visual Studio. I put a breakpoint in the protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost method.

Then, when I run the project http://localhost:58326/ comes up in a browser. I then had to actually browse to an endpoint like so: http://localhost:58326/Account/AccountService.svc in order to hit the breakpoint.

Now I can debug my programmatic configuration of the service. Hopefully this helps someone else.